# Filtering polygons that share more than 2 vertices using QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, vertices, adjacency

Is there a way to filter polygons that share more than 2 vertices with a feature?

I have multiple polygons, like in the image, but I just want to see those that touch more than one vertex of the main feature.

I can only go till this point with filter rule in symbology, working with touches($geometry).

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

It would select polygons from the layer where they intersect the source layer, then **only** for these, it would compute the intersection and if there is more than 1 point in the intersection, it returns the original shape (and fields).

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query. Replace the layer name for yours (`a` and `src`) and feel free to add any field you want from the source layer.

```sql
select a.*
from a
 join src
 on st_intersects(a.geometry, src.geometry)
WHERE ST_NPoints(st_intersection(a.geometry, src.geometry))>1
```

[image]