# Features filter based on geographical conditions in QGIS

Tags: qgis, filter

I use QGIS 3.10 on a MacOS 10.13 environment. I've got a point shapefile layer and a polygon shapefile layer. I want to set a filter to show (and work with) only those points that are within a certain polygon. I've tried the expression

```
intersects($geometry, geometry(get_feature('layer', 'attribute', 'value')))
```

that would work in the query builder, but not so in the filter builder. How can it be done?

Comment: This recent answer to a similar question would work for you I think re. using a virtual layer built on spatial SQL : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/387503/9880

Comment: So, you can't make it with a filter? The thing is that I'd rather not create new layers.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the expression to add a new field and use this one for your filter:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's an option, though it means adding a new column in the points layer for the intersection with each polygon.

Comment: yes a column in the layer which you want to filter, in the image above the orange (A) can be filterd like: "intersects"=1 which will only display polygons 2 and 3